# Laravel : Ajax delete with bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a bootstrap modal dialog (see image below)[image]

The red danger button (marked by xx) is where the action is happening. When that button is  clicked - the uploaded file ( in this case - 2013-09-18_16h40_47.png) should be deleted while the modal dialog box is still open which is not what is happening right now. The download id is not getting passed to the controller method **and** the modal dialog is closed when the red button is clicked.

UI code :

```
{{ Form::open( array('route' => 'download.deletedownload','method' => 'post','id' => 'form-add-setting') ) }}
                                                                    {{Form::hidden('downloadId',$download->id)}}
                                                                    <button id="downloadDelete" type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">xx</button> 
                                                                {{Form::close()}}
```

The route looks like this

```
Route::post('deletedownload', array('uses' => 'DownloadsController@deletedownload', 'as'=>'download.deletedownload'));
```

and the controller method look like this

```
public function deletedownload()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        dd("this is an ajax request");
    };
    var_dump('i am in the deletedownload method of the DownloadsController class');
    $id = Input::get('id');
    dd($id);
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Javascript :

```
   $('#downloadDelete').click(function (e)
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=URL::to('/')?>/deletedownload',
            data: 'dataString',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(result)
            {
               console.log(result);
            }
        })

    });
```

and this is the output

```
string(66) "i am in the deletedownload method of the DownloadsController class" NULL
```

Notice that "this is an ajax request" is not getting echoed. Hence i have reasons to believe that is not an ajax request.

Any help would be well appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Can you check Http headers for `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` in `deletedownload()` before everything starts. Everything looks good so far.

Comment: use the firebug or dev console in chrome.... see if a request is send.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Javascript ? Ajax request should be sent explicitly with Javascript or jQuery from the client side. I don't know if Ajax is already attached on that modal button ?

**UPDATE:**

As I can see you are using named route on a server side, but in Ajax request you are pointing to URL ?

Comment: @carousel- i am sorry , i forgot to attach that. I have updated my question with the javascript that i currently have.

Comment: I have tried using the named route in the JS but i still get the same result. So my URL looks like this : '<?=URL::route('download.deletedownload')?>'